# Invalid Method Reference when Referencing Declaring Interface

Tags: java, java-stream, method-reference

I'm creating some interfaces as part of a package to aid in the study of integer sequences, and when I tried to compile this:

```
package sequences;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface IntSequence extends IntegerSequence
{
    int term(int n);

    default int[] termsInRange(int start, int stop)
    {
        int[] result = new int[stop - start];
        for (int i = 0; i < stop - start; i++)
        {
            result[i] = term(start + i);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /*
     * Method "length" is defined in parent interface like so:
     * default int length() { return Integer.MAX_VALUE; }
     */
    default IntStream fullSequence(int start)
    {
        IntStream intermediate = start == 0 ? IntStream.range(start, length())
                                            : IntStream.rangeClosed(start, length());
        return intermediate.map(IntSequence::term);
    }
}
```

I was thrown this:

```
PS C:\Users\Sylvaenn\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Java\src> javac -d ..\cls -Xdiags:verbose sequences\IntSequence.java
sequences\IntSequence.java:24: error: method map in interface IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
                return intermediate.map(IntSequence::term);
                               ^
  required: IntUnaryOperator
  found: IntSequence::term
  reason: argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      cannot find symbol
        symbol:   method term(int)
        location: interface IntSequence
1 error
```

Considering that my method `term(int)` is clearly an `IntUnaryOperator`, and that replacing the method reference with `e -> term(e)` results in successful compilation, I am at a loss why I'm getting this error.

Just to make sure, I looked back at the method references section in the Java tutorial (the one on Oracle's website) and mine is in the category "Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type", which should be in the format `ContainingType::methodName`. Mine is in this format, so I've eliminated that as a potential cause.

Comment: I just tried `this::term` and it worked. Still, I'm curious as to why my first attempt didn't.

Answer (score 1):

After some thought, and after discovering that `this::term` worked in this case, I realized my mistake. My method reference does not reference an instance method of an arbitrary object of type `IntSequence`, as the implied object is not arbitrary. As `fullSequence` and `getTerm` are instance methods declared in the same interface, it is only logical that the compiler would assume a method reference in `fullSequence` that does not act upon an array or collection of `IntSequence`s refers to the current instance.